# Arithmetic with matrices

Tags: matrices

We have matrices

$$A=\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 2 \\
12 & 5
\end{bmatrix}
,
\quad
(AB)^{-1}=
\begin{bmatrix}
39 & -16 \\
-95 & 39
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now i woud like to solve matrix $B$ from this.

---

**Edit:** This is assignment for school so i encounter this as is. I know how matrix multiplication works, i also do know how inverse matrices work. Problem is that i didn't know where to begin from with this. Now with the hint mentioned i think i can solve this. Meaning i'm having trouble with the arithmetic with matrices for example $Ax=b \to X=A^{-1}b$.

Comment: Please tell us what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hint: $(AB)^{-1} = B^{-1}A^{-1}$...

Answer (score 3):

Hint:
$$
(AB)^{-1}=B^{-1}A^{-1} \quad \Rightarrow \quad(AB)^{-1}A=B^{-1} 
$$

Comment: So $$B^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} 30 & -16 \\ -9 & 39 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 5 & 2 \\ 12 & 5 \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Yes, Than the inverse gives $B$.

Comment: If we take inverse matrix from $B^{-1}$ that gives us $B$ right ?

Comment: This would give us $B=\begin{bmatrix}5 & 2 \\ 7 & 3\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Your $B^{-1}$ seems correct but $B$ is not.

Comment: Sorry i had typo in matrix $(AB)^{-1}$ it should be $(AB)^{-1}=\begin{bmatrix} 39 & -16 \\ -95 & 39 \end{bmatrix}$ i edited the post with correct numbers in it.